# How to show that the coupling $\pi$ is just uniformly distributed on the diagonal $D=\{(x,x):x\in [0,1]\}$?

Tags: real-analysis, probability

Let $\mu$ and $\nu$ be two uniform distributions on $[0,1]$. Let $\pi$ be the joint distribution of $\mu$ and $\nu$. Note that by disintegration theorem we have
$$
\pi(A\times B)=\int_A \pi_x(B)\mu(dx)
$$
for $A, B\subset [0,1]$ and $\pi_x$ is the disintegration.

Take $\pi_x=\delta_{f(x)}$ and $f(x):=x$. How to show that the coupling $\pi$ is just uniformly distributed on the diagonal $D=\{(x,x):x\in [0,1]\}$?

---

Then we have
$$
\pi(A\times B)=\int_A \delta_{f(x)}(B)\mu(dx)=\int_A I[x\in f^{-1}(B)]\mu(dx)=\int_{[0,1]}I[x\in f^{-1}(B)]I[x\in A]\mu(dx)
$$
Since $f(x)=x$, that is
$$
\pi(A\times B)=\int_{[0,1]}I[x\in B]I[x\in A]\mu(dx)=\int_{[0,1]}I[x\in A\cap B]\mu(dx)
$$

Why is this the diagonal?

Answer (score 1):

Your calculations are correct but you unnecessarily only look at sets of the form $A \times B$, however the diagonal is not of that form. Let $p_1$ be the projection to the first coordinate, i.e., $p_1(x,y) = x$, which is the map with respect to which you disintegrate.  For $z \in [0,1]$, define $D(z) := \{(x,x) \colon x \in [0,z]\}$, then by the disintegration theorem

$$ 
\mathbb{\pi}(D(z)) = \int_{0}^{1} \int_{p_1^{-1}(x)}1_{D(z)}(x,y)\pi_{x}(dy)\mu(dx) = \int_{0}^{1} 1_{D(z)}(x,x)\mu(dx) = \mu([0,z]) = z.
$$
More generally, by the same calculations as above we obtain for $C \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ that
$$
\pi(C) = \mu(\{x \in [0,1] \colon (x,x) \in C\}). 
$$
In this sense, $\pi$ is uniformly distributed on the diagonal.

Comment: Thanks! But I do not understand why there is $\int_{p_1^{-1}(x)} 1_{D(z)}$ inside the integral?

Comment: By disintegration theorem, $\pi(D(z))=\int_0^1\pi_x(B)\mu(dx)$. Is $B\subset [0,z]$? It seems that you write $\pi_x(B)=\int_B\pi_x(dy)$?

Comment: This is simply applying the disintegration theorem with the map $p$ (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disintegration_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem )

Comment: So the disintegration theorem you cite is a general version of what I wrote?